# Чтение из TreeMap по порядковому номеру?

Tags: java, коллекции

Приветствую, коллеги!

Есть готовый и отсортированный как надо `TreeMap`.

Как получить из него пары ключ-значение на основании порядкового номера `i`? По типу:

```
for (i = 0; i < map.size(); i++)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получить определенную пару по индексу `index` можно, например, так:

```
TreeMap<Object, Object> foo = new TreeMap<Object, Object>();
Object key = foo.keySet().toArray(new Object[foo.size()])[index];
Object value = foo.get(key);
```

Comment: Спасибо, оно!  Как подрастет репутация, смогу благодарить уже по-взрослому;)

Comment: Зачем каждый раз создавать массив, когда до нужного элемента можно добраться простой итерацией?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V> getEntryByIndex(Map<K, V> map, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || map.size() <= index) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("индекс выходит за границы");
    }
    Map.Entry<K, V> e = null;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (0 <= index--) {
        e = it.next(); 
    }
    return e;
}
```

Применение

```
Map<String, String> m = new TreeMap<String, String>() {{
    put("1", "1");
    put("2", "2");
}};

Map.Entry<String, String> e = getEntryByIndex(m, 1);
```

А если нужно просто в цикле получить все entry вместе с порядковым номером, то это совсем элементарно

```
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry e : m.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Порядковый номер: " + i);
    System.out.println("Ключ: " + e.getKey());
    System.out.println("Значение: " + e.getValue());
    i++; 
}
```